# In GeoDMS, how can we connect two arcs?

Tags: geospatial, geocoding, geo, geodms

In GeoDMS, I've loaded two networks from a shapefile, primaryNet and masterNet:

```
unit<uint32> primaryNet:
    storageName     = 'c:/localData/arnhemNijmegen/warmtenet/primair.dbf'
,   dialogData      = 'geometry'
,   dialogType      = 'map'
,   storageReadOnly = 'true'
{
    attribute<rdc>  geometry(arc):
        storageName     = 'c:/localData/arnhemNijmegen/warmtenet/primair.shp'
    ,   storageReadOnly = 'true';
}

unit<uint32> masterNet:
    storageName     = 'c:/localData/arnhemNijmegen/warmtenet/master.dbf'
,   dialogData      = 'geometry'
,   dialogType      = 'map'
,   storageReadOnly = 'true'
{
    attribute<rdc>  geometry(arc):
        storageName     = 'c:/localData/arnhemNijmegen/warmtenet/master.shp'
    ,   storageReadOnly = 'true';
}
```

I want to connect them into a new domain unit with a new geometry, containing both old geometries. All other attributes can be discarded. Is that possible?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean just unioning both arcsets to one new arcset with the geometries of both primaryNet and masterNet, Use the [union_unit](http://www.objectvision.nl/geodms/operators-a-functions/relational/union_unit) function to configure the resulting domain unit and the [union_data](http://www.objectvision.nl/geodms/opetrators-a-functions/relational/union_data) function to configure the resulting geometry attribute.

If you need connections between the two arcsets, can you indicate how these arcsets need to be connected?